# What fallacy is it to say all teenagers are bad, therefore all non-teenagers are not bad?

Tags: logic, fallacies

Suppose there is a non-empty subset A of U. Let A' denote the complement of A in U.

What is the name of this logical fallacy?

> X is true for A
> therefore
> not X is true for­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­ A'

For example, suppose U = {all people} and A = {all teenagers} then the logical fallacy is

> all teenagers are bad
> therefore
> all non-teenagers are not bad

Comment: Is there a reason you're using different notations for `not X` and `A'` ? Either is the complement of `X` or `A` (respectively).

Comment: @Flater If I used the same notation for X what would the superset be?

Comment: Actually, I could just use X ⊆ {bad, not bad}. If I had realized that earlier I might not have had to ask the question!

Comment: The definition of `not` inherently means that `{ X ,  not X }` is a complete set. You don't need to define it for every variable, negation is a basic operation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After some thought I realized this is a [denying the antecedent fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denying_the_antecedent). Put another way we have

> If the person is a teenager then they are bad
>   therefore
>   If the person is a non teenager then they are not bad

Comment: ‘Denying the antecedent’ correctly identifies the fallacy.  ‘All not-bad persons are not teenagers’ is the contrapositive.

Answer (score 14):

To add to @Jon's answer, denying the antecedent often comes up due to confusion with the valid argument form Modus Tollens

> ((p → q) ∧ ¬q) → ¬p)
> **or** ((if p then q) and not q) then not p)

Which is equivalent to

> (if p then q. Therefore, if not q then not p), i.e.
>
> *If a person is a teenager, then they are bad
>
> Therefore
>
> If a person is not bad, they are not a teenager*

Answer (score 0):

@willross1 currently writing a thesis on logical fallacies, new to this forum. I am confused about your account of modus tollens. I believe it is a simple clerical error in which you have accidentally forgotten a parentheses? There are too many close parentheses per open parentheses. Is this simply a keyboard error or am I too prone to misunderstand MT?
{[(p➡️q) & ~q] ➡️ ~q}

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Other contributors gave really interesting answers, yet no one mentioned the link to the classical confusion of necessity and sufficiency - the `X` is necessary for being an element of A, i.e. `A ⊆ T`, where `T = {t ∈ U | X is true for t}`. Yet no one guarantees that `A = T` (property is not a criterion), thus, `¬X` is not necessary for being an element of `A'` (unless `A = T` is stated), but it sufficient for being an element of `A'`. 
It could be demonstrated via the following Euler diagram (sorry for a sloppy picture): 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of **modus tollens**.

Say,

Q implies bad

P implies teenager

According to your problem,

P implies Q|!P|Therefore, !Q|

This shows that if teenager is bad, non-teenager means not bad.